# Storing Object States in java

Tags: java, performance, serialization, hashmap

I need to store a thousands objects states in a file, at the end of a time-cycle and bring them back to life in main memory with start of every new cycle.

so there are two ways I have thought of so far :

for example storing these objects directly as

```
class UsingClassObjects {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private long rollNo;
    private long credits;
```

}

or create a hashMap to store the states as:

```
class UsingHashMap{
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, HashMap<Long, Long>>> data = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, HashMap<Long, Long>>>();
```

}

So which of these two approaches is better memory and efficiency wise and why ?

and is there any even a better way to do so ?

and would serializing the object/s affect the performance rather than writing states to a plain text file, if I use the HashMap?

Comment: Is using a database not an option?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might find a non-relational database like MongoDB (https://www.mongodb.org) or an object-based solution like ObjectDB (http://www.objectdb.com)  suitable for your requirements. They are optimised for fast data retrieval.

Comment: The "UsingHashMap" option wasts a lot of memory as you have dozens, hundred or even thousand of HashMap instances. The data structure you need depends on how you access it, not how you are planning to store it.

Comment: @npinti no, using database is not an option

Comment: @Robert But There would be just one Main hashMap object containing lots of keys and their corresponding values (as nested hashMaps).

Comment: @Dhanesh Khurana Based on your definition you have one main HashMap containing multiple HashMaps each containing again multiple HashMaps. For every main HashMap entry you have at least two nested HashMaps. And every HashMap starts with a table of size 16 even if it only contains one element.

Comment: @Robert So I should store 10000 objects individually to create my cache ? Isn't there any efficient/optimized way ?

Comment: A HashMap can handle 10k objects without problem. The more important question is what you do with the data? Do you access it randomly (base don which field) or to you process everything sequentially?

Comment: @Robert I access it randomly to check some value and if needed then I update it. Nothing more as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the state in an HashMap is not a good option because:
1. In the end it is an object and it will dead if your server is crash or you stop the JVM.

2. If you are storing 1000 of object in HashMap which will increare the memory and there are chances to get Out of Memory issue.
3. HashMap will consume lot of memory for each entry object in it.

Hence I would recommend to use Java Serialization to store the state of an object which will preserve the state even if JVM is down.

Comment: What if I use serialization to to store that one hashMap rather than storing thousands of objects individually ?

Comment: What is if you want to update the Serialized version of 1 file i.e. new version of the Entity, in that case you have to deserialized complete Map which is unneccessary overhaed! and what is key to the HashMap you are thinking would be?

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the object and store in the File is much better than your HashMap approach as it can be wasteful. Also it will be trivial to serialize/deserialize a POJO if it is not complex. You can use a DB too and that can be helpful. You can use a Cache like REDIS also.